# how to multiply values with group of data from pandas series without loop iteration

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two pandas time series with different length and index, and a Boolean series. Series_1 is from the last data of each month with index last day of the month, series_2 is daily data with index daily, the Boolean series is True on the last day of each month, else as false.

I want to get data from series_1 (s1[0]) times data from series_2 (s2[1:n]) which is the daily data from one month, is there a way to do it without loop?

```
series_1 = 2010-06-30    1
           2010-07-30    2
           2010-08-31    5
           2010-09-30    7
series_2 = 2010-07-01    2
           2010-07-02    3
           2010-07-03    5
           2010-07-04    6
            .....
           2010-07-30     7
           2010-08-01     6
           2010-08-02     7
           2010-08-03     5
           .....
           2010-08-31     6
Boolean = False
          false
          ....
          True
          False
          False
          ....
          True
```

(with only the end of each month True)

want to get a series as a result that `s = series_1[i] * series_2[j:j+n]` (n data from same month)

How to make it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Have you taken a look at the pandas basics? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html

Comment: Yes, I did for sure....but it did not give me any clue yet....I could group series_2 by month then take each element in series-2 multiply each group....but was thinking there might be better way

Comment: or could try to convert series into dataframe with columns year index month.....then do multiplication ....not sure how to do that...

Comment: actually....as the datetime isn't continuous......there will not be prices on weekends while the new index for signal includes weekend and there will be a dropna() needed for final product .......was just wonder if can convert series into dataframe with columns as year index as month from the series itself......

Comment: resample using business days: `.resample('1B')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I got your question completely right but this should get you there:

```
series_1 = pd.Series({
    '2010-07-30': 2,
    '2010-08-31': 5
})

series_2 = pd.Series({
    '2010-07-01': 2,
    '2010-07-02': 3,
    '2010-07-03': 5,
    '2010-07-04': 6,
    '2010-07-30': 7,
    '2010-08-01': 6,
    '2010-08-02': 7,
    '2010-08-03': 5,
    '2010-08-31': 6
})
```

Make the series `Datetime` aware and resample them to daily frequency:

```
series_1.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(series_1.index)
series_1 = series_1.resample('1D').asfreq()

series_2.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(series_2.index)
series_2 = series_2.resample('1D').asfreq()
```

Put them in a dataframe and perform basic multiplication:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['1'] = series_1
df['2'] = series_2
df['product'] = df['1'] * df['2']
```

Result:

```
>>> df
              1    2  product
2010-07-30  2.0  7.0     14.0
2010-07-31  NaN  NaN      NaN
2010-08-01  NaN  6.0      NaN
2010-08-02  NaN  7.0      NaN
2010-08-03  NaN  5.0      NaN
[...]
2010-08-27  NaN  NaN      NaN
2010-08-28  NaN  NaN      NaN
2010-08-29  NaN  NaN      NaN
2010-08-30  NaN  NaN      NaN
2010-08-31  5.0  6.0     30.0
```

Comment: not really...but almost....series_1 is a trading signal and i want that single signal multiply each of the daily return (from series_2) from a month.......the product should be without Nan, as there is no nan in series_2

Comment: in that case you can replace `.asfreq()` by `.ffill()` when resampling `series_1`

Comment: can you accept the answer? then the question can be closed.